# Telegram Api - как перехватывать сообщение пользователей в канале

Tags: php, api, telegram

Необходимо создать бота, который будет перехватывать и слать на сервер все комментарии в чате. Подскажите пожалуйста методы и куда копать

Comment: так в документации есть информация, можно получать все сообщения